# Open helm-dash in emacs in a new window

Tags: helm, spacemacs, dash.el

When I'm editing my code, I'd like to open the documentation via `helm-dash-at-point` in a new split besides my source code. But it only opens in the same window. I don't really care if it uses `eww` or `w3m` as long as it works (eww would be slightly better).

I am using the latest Spacemacs with the newest Emacs.

(There are a couple of solutions that are supposed to work with Emacs proper but don't with Spacemacs)